# Verifying a non-virtual method in base class is called using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, xamarin, moq

This post requires the base class methods to be virtual: [question link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21147777/133992).

This does not work for me because the base class methods are not virtual (I did not write it and do not have source).

How do I mock out and verify the base class method was called if they are not virtual?

Last criteria - I am developing using Xamarin Studio on Mac.  Moq works fine but other frameworks like TypeMock or JustMock (windows install programs) will not work.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738102/how-to-mock-non-virtual-methods

Comment: @StuartLC removed. Wrong paste.

Comment: @JuanLopes thanks for the link but since I am using  Xamarin Studio on Mac, I don't believe those products will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. Because of the way Moq works, there is no chance Moq can mock a non-virtual method.

Are you mocking the class type `YourClass` directly, where `YourClass` derives from `BaseClass`, and `BaseClass` has this (`public`?) non-virtual non-static method that interests you? So your mock has type `Mock<YourClass>`, not `Mock<IYourClass>` where `IYourClass` is an interface?

Is it strictly necessary that you use `BaseClass` as a base class, rather than "composing" (having a field of type `BaseClass` insider your class)?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, Moq can only mock virtual methods. 
One possible end run is to wrap your un-moqable class in a proxy and use this proxy in your code.

```
public class MyUnMoqableClass {
    public string GetValue() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}

public interface IMyUnMoqableClassProxy {
    string GetValue();
}

public class UnMoqableClassProxy : IMyUnMoqableClassProxy {

    private readonly MyUnMoqableClass _myUnMoqableClass;

    public UnMoqableClassProxy(MyUnMoqableClass myUnMoqableClass) {
        _myUnMoqableClass = myUnMoqableClass;
    }

    public string GetValue() {
        return _myUnMoqableClass.GetValue();
    }

}
```

It can be a bit (a lot) tedious if you have a large interface on the unmoqable class but does let one isolate the client code.

Comment: Yes this is what I ended up doing - I had to isolate the class that was unmock-able by moq.  thanks.