# Unit test to verify that a base class method is called

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a base class:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    protected virtual void Method1()
    {    
    }
}
```

and a derived class:

```
public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public void Method2()
    {
        base.Method1();
    }
}
```

I want to write a unit test for `Method2` to verify that it calls `Method1` on the base class. I'm using Moq as my mocking library. Is this possible?

I came across a related SO link:

[Mocking a base class method call with Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293151/mocking-a-base-class-method-call-with-moq)

in which the 2nd answer suggests it can be achieved by setting `CallBase` property to true on the mock object. However it's not clear how this would enable the call to the base class method (`Method1` in the above example) to be verified.

Appreciate any assistance with this.

Comment: Why is it a requirement that the base method is called? If you mock it, all you are verifying that the _mock_ calls the base method.  Are you just verifying that the `base.` syntax works or do you _need_ inherited classes to call the base?

Comment: Also, you should only be testing that the _results_ are correct.  Testing that a particular _implementation_ is used is generally an indication of a bad design.

Comment: Does the base method have side effects that you can verify?

Comment: @DStanley Yes there are side effects that can be verified and I think that's probably the route I'll take. I was just wondering if it's indeed possible using mocking libraries such as Moq to verify that a base class method is called from a derived class.

Comment: Possibly, but it makes a lot more sense to verify the _results_ rather than the _implementation_.  Plus it frees you up to change the implementation without having to re-write your tests (so long as the _results_ are correct).

Comment: In your current implementation, you can't intercept the call with Moq, however since `MyDerivedClass` doesn't implement `Method1`, you could remove the `base.` prefix from the call and then you would be able to intercept the call.  This is likely to be the *right* thing to do anyway, since otherwise you're cutting derived implementations of `Method1` out which feels wrong.  Further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31201708/592182 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/31062287/592182

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Original method still getting called in Moq even after CallBase = true/false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198854/original-method-still-getting-called-in-moq-even-after-callbase-true-false)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unit tests should verify *behavior*, not *implementation*.  There are several reasons for this:

- The results are the goal, not how you *get* the results
- Testing results allows you to improve the implementation without re-writing your tests
- Implementations are harder to mock

You *might* be able to put in hooks or create mocks that verify that the base method was called, but do you really care *how* the answer was achieved, or do you care that the answer is *right*?

If the particular implementation you require has side effects that you can verify, then *that* is what you should be validating.

Comment: Good answer(+1)... One more important thing for the OP: If you won't verify the expected behavior of the method under test then future changes in the base class may break the CUT behavior without and notification...

Comment: If you are not testing for implementation details then how do you enforce new changes don't break critical steps that need to be taken. EG. `class Query` calls `Execute` which itself calls two methods `Where` and `Sort`. Say I'm a new hire and I go and remove the call to `Sort` now my class is not performing as expected.

Comment: @Adrian The unit test should verify that the _results_ are still correct (meaning that they are properly sorted in this case). My point is you should not care (from a unit test perspective) that the specific `Sort` method is called or whether a different `Sort` method is called, or just sorted within the `Execute` method.

Comment: Ok, that makes total sense. This has actually helped me think about unit testing in a different light. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Mocking the base class from the perspective of the derived class is not possible.  In your simple example, I would suggest one of the two options.

Option 1: In the event that `MyDerivedClass` really shouldn't care what `MyBaseClass` is up to, then use dependency injection!  Yay abstraction!

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IUsedToBeBaseClass myDependency;

    public MyClass(IUsedToBeBaseClass myDependency){
        _myDependency = myDependency;
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        _myDependency.Method1();
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in test land...

```
[TestClass]
public class TestMyDependency {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestThatMyDependencyIsCalled() {
        var dependency = new Mock<IUsedToBeBaseClass>();
        var unitUnderTest = new MyClass(dependency.Object);
        var unitUnderTest.Method2();
        dependency.Verify(x => x.Method1(), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

Option 2:  In the event that `MyDerivedClass` NEEDS to know what `MyBaseClass` is doing, then **test that `MyBaseClass` is doing the right thing**.

In alternative test land...

```
[TestClass]
public class TestMyDependency {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestThatMyDependencyIsCalled() {
        var unitUnderTest = new MyDerivedClass();
        var unitUnderTest.Method2();
        /* verify base class behavior #1 inside Method1() */
        /* verify base class behavior #2 inside Method1() */
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you're describing is not a test of your code, but a test of the behavior of the language. That's fine, because it's a good way to ensure that the language behaves the way we think it does. I used to write lots of little console apps when I was learning. I wish I'd known about unit testing then because it's a better way to go about it.

But once you've tested it and confirmed that the *language* behaves the way you expect, I wouldn't keep writing tests for that. You can just test the behavior of your code.

Here's a real simple example:

```
public class TheBaseClass
{
    public readonly List<string> Output = new List<string>();

    public virtual void WriteToOutput()
    {
        Output.Add("TheBaseClass");
    }
}

public class TheDerivedClass : TheBaseClass
{
    public override void WriteToOutput()
    {
        Output.Add("TheDerivedClass");
        base.WriteToOutput();
    }
}
```

Unit test

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void EnsureDerivedClassCallsBaseClass()
    {
        var testSubject = new TheDerivedClass();
        testSubject.WriteToOutput();
        Assert.IsTrue(testSubject.Output.Contains("TheBaseClass"));
    }
```